# Как разместить в GAC сборку , минуя gacutil.exe или Windows Installer?

Tags: c#, wpf

Вопрос:
Я использую в своем приложении сборку Extended WPF Toolkit и разворачиваю свое приложение через `ClickOnce`, но при установке дистрибутива , подготовленного `ClickOnce`, получаю:

> "Невозможно установить или запустить
> приложение. Для этого приложения
> необходимо сначала установить сборку
> WPFToolkit.Extended Версия 1.6.0.0 в
> глобальный кэш сборок (GAC)."

При попытке зарегистрировать сборку с помощью gacutil.exe получаю сообщение:

> Microsoft (R) .NET Global Assembly
> Cache Utility.  Version 3.5.30729.1
> Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. 
> All rights reserved.
>
> Failure adding assembly to the cache: 
> Сборка создана в более поздней версии
> среды выполнения чем текущая, и не
> может быть загружена.

Приложение без инсталлера нормально запускается, но я хотел опробовать сделать обновление программы, а в `ClickOnce` оно вроде как реализовано. Windows Installer же регистрирует сборку в GAC , но тогда надо что-то другое придумать с обновлениями.

Comment: А если поставить сборке Copy Local в true? Пускай тащит ее вместе с остальными файлами

Comment: так и стоит , к сожалению, не помогает (

Comment: @fundottz лучше поздно, чем никогда. в студии есть глюк, из-за которого она не копирует сборки с отметкой Copy Local если они есть в GAC. Чтобы его обойти, надо поменять Copy Local на false, сохранить проект, потом поменять обратно на true.

Comment: @PashaPash: А почему не как ответ?

Comment: @VladD потому что вопрос вообще не о том. придется переписывать его полностью, включая заголовок. а баг исправили пару лет назад, и ответ никому уже не поможет. хотя, может быть и стоит перенести, но уже не сегодня.

Comment: @PashaPash: Ну, если начать ответ с «Ваша проблема решается следующим образом: ...» и закончить «Но в современных версиях Visual Studio этой проблемы больше нет, её исправили.», то должно подойти?

Answer (score 3):

Первоначальная проблема именно в том, что сборка, отмеченная Copy Local, не копируется в папку bin.

Это вызвано старым багов в студии - для референсов, добавленных из GAC, в свойствах отображается Copy Local = true, но при билде сборки на самом деле не копируются.

Для обхода бага достаточно поменять Copy Local на false, и потом обратно на true.

Это добавит в csproj-файл элемент `<Private>True</Private>`:

```
<ProjectReference Include="..\CoreServices\CoreServices.csproj">
  <Project>{01C58D27-9818-45D6-A0B6-8EF765CA9397}</Project>
  <Name>CoreServices %28CoreServices\CoreServices%29</Name>
  <Private>True</Private>
</ProjectReference>
```

Баг в том, что при добавлении новой сборки Copy Local проставляется в true по умолчанию. Но при этом сам флаг не сохраняется в файл проекта. При билде же студия использует флаг из файла проекта, и при его отсутствии - пропускает сборки из GAC.

<sub>[Пост на MSDN Blogs - The "Copy Local" Bug in Visual Studio](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jjameson/the-copy-local-bug-in-visual-studio)</sub>

В новых версиях студии это исправлено, по крайней мере на 2013 Update 4 баг не воспроизводится.

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант, попробуйте рантайм дотнета обновить на той машине, на которой появляется сообщение

> Сборка создана в более поздней версии среды выполнения чем текущая, и не может быть загружена.

Comment: сборка под .net 4.0 , он же и стоит или еще что-то обновить можно?

Comment: Судя по еррорам кликванс пытается засунуть сборку в гак фреймворка версии 3.5, а она 4.0 Возможно в нем етот момент как то настраивается-меняется? (не работал с ним) И еще мне кажется должен быть способ устанавливать приложение без ГАКа (хранить сборки локально в папке), хотя не уверен.